# complexity of calling a function n times

Tags: complexity-theory

lets say I have a function `sort` that has O(n log n) complexity. Now If I have a list of `k` lists, each of a different length how would I go about calculating the total complexity of calling `sort` on each element in the list?

It seems to be the sum from 1 to k of

```
O(n1 log n1) + O(n2 log n2) + O(n3 log n3) ...
```

where each n is of arbitrary length.

Comment: that's it. you can not do more. may be you can manipulate it to O(log(\prod n_i ^ n_i))

Comment: @mbcoder, can you put this as an answer and i'll accept